# How to install executable for crystallreports?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, c#-4.0, crystal-reports

i have been working on installing crystal reports sp9 for Visual studio 2013, it got downloaded and i installed .msi file `CRRuntime_64bit_13_0_12`

but documentation says that ***"you must run the Install Executable. Running the MSI will not fully integrate Crystal Reports into VS. MSI files by definition are for runtime distribution only."***

now what does install executable mean ? how i will get it ?

http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824

Answer (score 1):

Please click on the link Support Pack 12 (v.13.0.12.1494) on the executable column of the downloads table. This should start downloading the CRforVS_13_xx.exe file.